generate a random number whose reminder modulo t is given, without division
Suppose we have a random number generator, returning a  $n$-bit integer (e.g. uint64_t) I wish to manipulate the number so that it will return a uniform random $n$-bit integer, but with a reminder $r$ modulo $t$.
Given that the random number is $x$. One way to achieve it is to do $$\foor(x/t)\cdot t +r$$, but this uses a long division, which might be ineffective slowing down the generator.
In order to reduce time compleixty, if there is an implementations that uses only addition and shifts, I will be grateful for that.
What can I do?

This is just math. result = r + t * uniform_random(0, ((1<<n) - 1)/ t - 1) /* with some tweaking if t is an exact multiple of (1<<n)-1) */. If n and t are a constant, then the division can be folded at compile time.

You cannot use another random number generator, and you must use  the n-bit RNG

As you can see, Stack Overflow does not support TeX, so your equations are not legible. Please fix this.

In which case, you can create a uniform random number generator from your original one.

Maybe you can do:
x = random_uint64()

result = x - (x % t) + r

example:
x = 29
t = 3
r = 2

result = 29 - (29 % 3) + 2
result = 29 - (2) + 2
result = 29

Or you could generate a random number such that x * t does not overflow the number.
Then you could simply do:
result = x * t + r


modulo and division have the same time complexity, and are usually slower than addion\shifts
